# Создание хлебных крошек | Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework-2

Имею в файле конфигураций описанную "навигацию":

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factrories' => array(
        'navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',
        'navAdmin' => 'Admin\Lib\AdminNavigationFactory',
    ),
),

'navigation' => array(
    'default' => array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Главная',
            'route' => 'admin',
        ),
    ),
    'nav_admin' => array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Панель управления сайтом',
            'route' => 'admin',
            'action' => 'admin',
            'resource' => 'Admin\Controller\Admin',

            'pages' => array(
                array(
                    'label' => 'Управление новостями',
                    'route' => 'admin/news-cp',
                    'action' => 'news',
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => 'Добавить категорию',
                    'route' => 'admin/news-cp',
                    'action' => 'news',
                    'subAction' => 'add',
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => 'Добавить новость',
                    'route' => 'admin/news-cp',
                    'action' => 'news',
                    'subAction' => 'add',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

В этом же файле маршруты:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(

        'admin' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/admin',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller'    => 'Admin\Controller\Admin',
                    'action'        => 'admin',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'news-cp' => array(
                    'type' => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/news-cp[/]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*',
                            'element' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'news',
                            'action' => 'news'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'add-edit-delete' => array(
                    'type' => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/news-cp[/:action/][:subAction/][:element/][:elementName/][:id]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*',
                            'elementName' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'news',
                            'action' => 'news'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ), // < child routes
        ),

    ),
),
```

В файле *AdminNavigationFactory*:

```
<?php 
namespace Admin\lib; 
use Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory;
class AdminNavigationFactory extends DefaultNavigationFactory
{
    protected function getName()
    {
        return 'nav_admin';
    }
}
```

У меня такая проблема:
При отображении (

```
<?php echo $this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setPartial();?>
```

)не работает, выдавая ошибку 500.

На локальном сервере удалось получить полную ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решён. Была ошибка в одном из слов...
как обычно :)